# MacOS connecting to a non-internet server on local network

Tags: network, webserver

I have 2 Mac (Mac Book and Mac Book Air), one running Catalina 10.15.5 (19F101) and the other one Mojave 10.14

I have a server NOT connected to the Internet, with Tomcat setup and it's all hooked to a local network, many computer connect to it via WiFi.

The address is something like `88.110.19.73`, when opening Chrome on Windows and going to `http://88.110.19.73` it connects correctly to the network and Tomcat serves the web-app correctly, any Windows computer connects fine to it.

When connecting from a Mac (any of the above and even other Macs) it says `No Internet` with error: `ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED`

The computer is correctly connected to the correct WiFi Network.
Actually the "no internet" is correct, but how do I access that network service from a Mac?

I tried turning off the Firewall with no luck.

Comment: Where’d you get that IP because it’s not a private network address? As for your network, what does your IP address scheme look like?  Finally, what’s the IP address of the Mac that can’t connect?  What’s the gateway set to?

Comment: That IP was given to me by the administrator. I know it does not look like a private network actually... My IP scheme once connected to that network is 10.100.X.XX. When I ping that 88.XXX. IP this is what I get: PING 88.110.19.73 (88.110.19.73):
56 data bytes
ping: sendto: No route to host
ping: sendto: No route to host
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0

Comment: Ok.  Then you need to reach out to your network admin to assist because we have no idea what your network looks like or how its configured. Only your admin will know that

Comment: I can tell you that the error message you’re getting is a routing issue, but the questions I have, only the admin would  have the answers.  Typically, if you show him the errors, he can solve it quicker thank us going back and forth as he shoukd know exactly where to look.